# Calling another contract in my implementation contract

Tags: solidity

I have a UUPS upgradeable contract, where in this contract I want to call some functions of another contract. For example:

```
contract TestContract is UUPSUpgradeable {
    AnotherContract public contractInstance;

    function initialize(address contractAddress) public initializer {
        contractInstance = AnotherContract(contractAddress);
    }

    function testFunction() public {
        contractInstance.anotherFunction(....)
    }
}
```

But seems like it cannot find `anotherFunction` in the `contractInstance`. I suspect we have to use delegatecall here, but would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Isn't _authorizeUpgrade() missing here?

Comment: You don't need to use a delegate call if you are not trying to call the target contract as the `msg.sender`. Please include the error message

Answer (score 0):

I think you need Interface for that contract to call it like this , without interface  you can use low level calls i.e. - call, send for making a call , i would recommend.call() with custom gas provided ( for this read about call vs send vs transfer)